Correctly Managing Order of Expansion with Environments
In a previous question, I asked how to conditionally print out 'answers' to a list at the bottom of the document (involving storing a list into a sequence and conditionally printing out the answers), which works as expected.
However, I am now trying to make this compatible with nested lists. To prevent multiple lists from being saved in the solutions, I have introduced \g_qlist_level_int where the list is only saved when \g_qlist_level_int = {1} to prevent duplication.
As you will see in the MWE below, the issue with nested lists is that the 'question' content is immediatelly elimianted when \printAnswers is used, not allowing for the nested list to be accessed.
MWE
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{enumitem}

    % Redefine \section to also store the section name
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\thesectionname}{}
    \renewcommand{\section}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{section}%
    \renewcommand{\thesectionname}{#1}%
    \par\medskip\noindent\textbf{\thesection\ #1}\par\medskip
    }
    \makeatother

    \ExplSyntaxOn

    \bool_new:N \g_exercise_questions_bool
    \bool_gset_true:N \g_exercise_questions_bool

    \seq_new:N \g_Harry_listcontent_seq

    \int_new:N \g_qlist_level_int

    \NewDocumentEnvironment{exercises}{+b}
        {%
        \int_gincr:N \g_qlist_level_int
        \int_compare:nNnTF {\g_qlist_level_int} = {1}
            {\seq_gput_right:Ne \g_Harry_listcontent_seq
                {
                \exp_not:N \subsection { \exp_not:V \thesectionname }
                \exp_not:n
                    {
                        \begin{myList}%
                            #1
                        \end{myList}%
                    }
                }
            }{}
            {
            \begin{myList}%
                #1
            \end{myList}%
            }
            \int_gdecr:N \g_qlist_level_int
        }
        {%
        }%

    \NewDocumentEnvironment{myList}{}
        % set-up so that list styling can be applied once and reused (twice) in the above list since we need to print it twice, once in the \seq and once to print the actual content when invoked; if there is a cleaner way to do this, please let me know.
        {%
            \begin{enumerate}
        }{%
            \end{enumerate}%
        }%

    \NewDocumentCommand{\myitem}{ m O{} }{
        \item 
            \bool_if:NTF \g_exercise_questions_bool
            {#1} %this is the problem, this causes everything within here to not print. Please see below for elaboration.
            {#2}
    }

    \NewDocumentCommand{\printAnswers}{ }{
        \bool_gset_false:N \g_exercise_questions_bool
        \section{Answers}
        \seq_use:Nn \g_Harry_listcontent_seq {\par}
        \bool_gset_true:N \g_exercise_questions_bool
    }

    \ExplSyntaxOff


    \begin{document}

        \section{The First Section}

            \begin{exercises}
                \myitem{q11}{
                    \begin{exercises}
                        \myitem{q11a}[s11a]
                        \myitem{q11b}[s11b]
                    \end{exercises}}
                \myitem{q12}[s12]
            \end{exercises}


        \section{The Second Section}

            \begin{exercises}
                \myitem{q21}[s21]
                \myitem{q22}[s22]
            \end{exercises}

    \printAnswers

    \end{document}

I am looking for a way to try and modify:
    \NewDocumentCommand{\myitem}{ m O{} }{
        \item 
            \bool_if:NTF \g_questions_bool
            {#1} %this is the problem, this causes everything within here to not print. Please see below for elaboration.
            {#2}
    }

So that nested lists, within #1, don't get cut out. In a previous version of this question (now edited), I was trying to use a system of starting and ending environments to get around the above problem, with something like:
    \item
    % \startCommentOut
    % question content to comment out
    % -- Nested list starts --
    %   - \endCommentOut inserted by the list to break to comment out sequence and bring the list back in
    % \begin{myList}
    % \end{myList}
    %   - \startCommentOut inserted by the list to resume to comment out sequence as before
    % -- Nested list ends --
    % any further content commented out...

I have a genuine use-case for this with content getting dynamically generated from a program and it works ideally to be able to achieve the use case that I have above.
@cfr has suggested (I believe) using:
    \begin{exercises}
        \myitem{q11}
            \begin{exercises}
                \myitem{q11a}[s11a]
                \myitem{q11b}[s11b]
            \end{exercises}
        \myitem{q12}[s12]
    \end{exercises}

Rather than:
    \begin{exercises}
        \myitem{q11
            \begin{exercises}
                \myitem{q11a}[s11a]
                \myitem{q11b}[s11b]
            \end{exercises}
        }
        \myitem{q12}[s12]
    \end{exercises}

This is not possible however, as this will compromise functionality required for \myitem see another question here. I am happy to expand the above and elaborate further if needed however.
Looking ideally to be able to output with the following code:
        \section{The First Section}

            \begin{exercises}
                \myitem{q11
                    \begin{exercises}
                        \myitem{q11a}[s11a]
                        \myitem{q11b}[s11b]
                    \end{exercises}
                }
                \myitem{q12}[s12]
            \end{exercises}


        \section{The Second Section}

            \begin{exercises}
                \myitem{q21}[s21]
                \myitem{q22}[s22]
            \end{exercises}

    \printAnswers

The below

Rather than the current output:


you have defined \myitem with second argument optional but show usage such as \myitem{Question should not print}{Solutions should print} with two {..} mandatory arguments. Which do you intend?

Apologies, that was an error. I have corrected this now.

you could have edited your question rather than deleting it and writing another about basically the same thing.

Apologies, will do so in future. Thank you.

by the way, in expl3 all your variables and functions should use a unique prefix. so you should have e.g. \g_harry_questions_bool or whatever and not just \g_questions_bool. Redefining \section is not really a good idea ....

why can't you just have \myitem{q11}  <rest of it>? or \myitem{q11} {<rest of it>}? or some similar variant? why do you need \myitem{q11 <rest of it>}? off-topic: I wouldn't use underscores in the names of environments. that's asking for trouble.

Addressed, but essentially there is more going on in \myitem ultimately (it all needs to be saved in a list and inserted, and then will also be wrapped in a minipage to put marks on the right).

the markup you're aiming for is illogical. you are putting bits of solutions into questions, telling tex not to print the questions and then looking for a way to persuade it to nonetheless print bits of the questions after all. I don't see it really matters the wider context (at least, not as described) because you can add things to whatever token lists/content building-blocks you need in any case. this doesn't just seem unnecessarily tricky in terms of doing it in tex. it seems like a confusing design.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The root cause of this is needing to use tasks and enumitem interchangeably (I think you saw the other ticket I raised). We also need questions and solutions to be paired together in the way that I describe to be compatible with AI content models that we are using. They don't play nice with dumping out answers beneath the questions (in the conventional way in which they are done in LaTeX).
It is complicated, but then what is the alternative to being able to have:

columns on command
solutions paired with questions and then capability to dump solutions at the end


you are using b arguments (why?) which means that the code has to scan ahead without expansion looking for \end{...} so you can not hide the end code in a macro. (This is similar to the constraint in amsmath that you can not hide \end{align} inside a command definition unless the \begin is in the same definition.

Was using b so that I could 'comment out' the body. But even with:
    {\end{mycomment}\begin{enumerate}}
    {\end{enumerate}\begin{mycomment}}```

Output is still the same

I'm not fixed on this method by the way, if there is another way to achieve the expected output that works!

are you really commited to the (somewhat weird) syntax which is not impossible but rather hard and fragile to implement, with an initial omitted section that has no markup other than the \begin{myenum} which ends (!!???) the omitted section @Harry

I tried to simplify this to resolve the issue, but I think I've confused how I intend for this to work. I will delete this and raise a new question with my actual code which will make this clearer, apologies.

@Harry you can edit questions rather than deleting them. this version is a bit different because it has an answer rather than just comments, but, if it is really the same question, it is usually better to edit. cases where you will invalidate an existing answer are different. (but if you are otherwise going to delete both question and answer anyway, the don't-invalidate guideline doesn't really get a grip.)

@cfr and David, I have edited the question now to include full scope and context. Hopefully this makes it clear what I am attempting to achieve.
